# connections were in use and max pool size was reached

Tags: connection-pooling, .net-5

I am working on dotnet core 5.0 and I am facing this error message:

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

I set these parameters to my connection string

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User Id=sa;password=admin123;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=100;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

This is how I deal with DB:

```
using (CD_DataToolContext objCDContext = new CD_DataToolContext()) 
{
     List<CdStandardFile> standardFiles = new List<CdStandardFile>(); 
     foreach (var item in data) {
         CdStandardFile cdStandardFile = new CdStandardFile(); 
         standardFiles.Add(cdStandardFile); 
     } 
     objCDContext.AddRange(standardFiles); objCDContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: I think its not about connection string. Somewhere in your code you have connection leaks. Please share a minimum code that demonstrates how are you dealing with database.

Comment: Also, according to this: `Max Pool Size=100`, does your application use more than 100 connections to DB in same time?

Comment: using (CD_DataToolContext objCDContext = new CD_DataToolContext())
                    {
                        List<CdStandardFile> standardFiles = new List<CdStandardFile>();
                        foreach (var item in data)
                        {
                            CdStandardFile cdStandardFile = new CdStandardFile(); standardFiles.Add(cdStandardFile);
                        } objCDContext.AddRange(standardFiles);
                        objCDContext.SaveChanges();
                       
                    }

Comment: Actually I need to add 40K plus records in db for that I use using inside task factory and from ajax request I send data in 1000 chunks

Comment: This is not how .Net Core applications supposed to work. You need to register your `CD_DataToolContext` as a service in `Startup.cs` and inject it in your class. I think this is the reason that you have connection leaks. You can read this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I add dbContext as a singleton service but for this method I use new db object so that my whole application will not depend upon one object

Comment: services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); I add this a use for other operations

Comment: This could be a limitation if you are using a consumption Plan
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#connection-limit
If this is the case then you might need to upgrad to Premium Plan 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits.
But be sure of the root cause if you are planning to upgrade to premium plan